# Python is not reading the complete image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-tesseract

I am trying to read a specific section of an image. My code reads almost everything leaving just one character.

`

```
  from PIL import Image
  from pytesseract import image_to_string, pytesseract
  import cv2
  import pytesseract

  im = Image.open("Path_to_base_image/sam2.png")
  crop_im2 = im.crop((2,256,280,389)) #This is where I am reading my text from
  crop_im2_1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/kandw1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/areverse/crop_im2.png')
    
  img = cv2.cvtColor(crop_im2_1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
  ret, thresh4 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  cv2.imshow('Set to 0', thresh4)
                                                                
 cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/kandw1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/areverse/bw.png', thresh4)
  if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

 crop_im2.save('Path_where_I_am_saving_cropped_image/crop_im2.png')
    
    img2 = cv2.imread('Path_where_my_cropped_image_is/bw.png')
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
    
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img2, config=custom_config))
```

`

The above code generates below output

`CLASSIC`

`FI`

P.s. I am disgustingly new to python and might be missing out on something very basic. Please help me figure it out.
[image]

I edited my code to convert the cropped image to a black & white image and then read from it. Also, I changed the underlying font. So the issue seems to have gone but even then the output generated is not satisfactory. What approach can I take to get over this.

[image]

My new output after b/w thresholding is as follows

`CLASSIC`
`PUT`

I am using

1. Pillow version == 8.2.0
2. opencv-python==4.5.1.48
3. Python 3.8.8

Comment: This works for me, prints FIT, not FI, with tesseract 5.0.

Comment: I am using tesseract 5.0.0-alpha.20201127 and I cannot figure out what is it that I am missing :(

Comment: I installed tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0.20190623.exe from (https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/) (on Windows 10)

Comment: I installed the same version as you mentioned. Same issue. But if I change the text from FIT to FITTEST; it works just fine. What could possible explain this! Python playing games eh!

Comment: @Potatojaisiladki What versions of OpenCV and Pillow are you using? Run `pip freeze` to get the version numbers. Also, the version of python you're currently using will help  everyone troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I have edited as per your advise